# Moved Site - Can't find original CSS for look other than in the ADVAGG

Tags: 7, theming

I've inherited a drupal 7(I'm a beginner) site that had ADVagg installed. I added a stanza in my nginx config to take care of those files. What I'm running into is that there is a button on the original site that has a style which only exists in an aggregate file.  I can't find it in any other file in the enitre site. The docroot was zipped and sent to me. I'm just a little miffed as to why the site I've unpacked doesn't have the same styles as the one online currently.

I've disabled the ADVAGG as well with no change.

```
###
    ### advagg_css and advagg_js support
    ###
    location ~* files/advagg_(?:css|js)/ {
      gzip_static on;
      access_log  off;
      expires     max;
      add_header  ETag "";
      add_header  Cache-Control "max-age=31449600, no-transform, public";
      try_files   $uri @rewrite;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AdvAgg is used to improve the standard Drupal Core aggregation.

Just disabling AdvAgg won't disable aggregation.

You will need to disable CSS aggregation under the Performance settings, then flush caches, and you should be able to inspect the button CSS again.